# Not seeing Serilog CloseAndFlush

Tags: serilog

Just getting into SeriLog. Should mention now that this a class library in .Net standard (i.e. not Core). Using SeriLog 2.10.0, Sinks.File 4.1.0, and Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.6.0.

Having issues with the SQL Server sink, and realized that I was not calling CloseAndFlush like all the examples said I should do. Problem is it is not available, Intellisense doesn't even show it. Key parts of my code, the class constructor and method GetCB:
[image]

[image]

so why am I not seeing CloseAndflush? I'll post my other issues later. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is in the static Log class.

```
Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

Also you should know that this method needs to be called only once in the application life cycle.  For example when the application ends.

Comment: Right, so in my case is calling Dispose() the correct approach?

Comment: @THedge I think you should reuse the instance of the logger. I usually make it a singleton.  And you should not expect serilog to send the logs right away... Sometimes it will wait for a "non busy" moment in your app to send the logs.